# .Net-Docker .UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfd in position error

Tags: c#, .net, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a project which include some microservices. I am using Docker in this project. But recently it give some errors like this on rebuild: (I opened this file with notepad and saved it as UTF-8 format but not solved..)

[image]

Comment: The error is likely in your docker-compose.yml

Comment: @KlausGütter your are absolutely right... The error was is in docker-compose.yml file.  I added some comments containing Turkish characters to this page. (Like this : Şş, Öö, Ğğ, ğ ,ı, çÇ) So visual studio give me this message. When I changed this letters with english versions then error solved. Thank you for showing my way.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the error..
In the docker-compose.override.yml file,  I added some comments containing Turkish characters to this page. (Like this : **Şş, Öö, Ğğ ,Iı, çÇ**) So visual studio give me this message. When I changed this letters with english versions (**Ss, Oo, Gg, Cc**) then error solved.

**Namely: docker-compose.yml  doesnt accept Turkish characters even if it is in the comment lines.**

[image]